# MySQL installation with Ansible on Debian Wheezy

Tags: mysql, debian, ansible, debconf

As the title suggests, I am trying to install MySQL Server 5.5 on Debian with Ansible.

Since this needs to be a silent installation, I provide the root password before the installation with debconf module. Here's the output for this:

```
changed: [nqdo-net] => (item={'value': {'type': 'password', 'name': 'mysql-server/root_password', 'value': u'XXXXthisismyrandomandlongpasswordXXXX'}, 'key': 'root_password'})
changed: [nqdo-net] => (item={'value': {'type': 'password', 'name': 'mysql-server/root_password_again', 'value': u'XXXXthisismyrandomandlongpasswordXXXX'}, 'key': 'root_password_again'})
```

I wrote a role to install Tripwire like this and it works like a charm. But unfortunately, MySQL installation fails with this message:

```
140901 21:24:55 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
140901 21:24:55 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
140901 21:24:55 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140901 21:24:55 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140901 21:24:55 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
140901 21:24:55 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
140901 21:24:55 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
140901 21:24:55 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12
140901 21:24:55 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
140901 21:24:55 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
140901 21:24:55 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
140901 21:24:55 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.

140901 21:24:55 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
140901 21:24:55 [ERROR] Aborting

140901 21:24:55 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

Configuring mysql-server-5.5
----------------------------

Unable to set password for the MySQL "root" user

An error occurred while setting the password for the MySQL administrative user. This may have happened because the account already has a password, or because of a communication problem with the MySQL server.

You should check the account's password after the package installation.

Please read the /usr/share/doc/mysql-server-5.5/README.Debian file for more
information.

insserv: warning: script 'K01confluence' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'confluence' missing LSB tags and overrides
[FAIL] Starting MySQL database server: mysqld . . . . . . . . . . . . . . failed
!
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1

msg: 'apt-get install 'mysql-server-5.5' ' failed: E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg
returned an error code (1)
```

Any idea on how to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

**Note:** If you are downvoting, at least tell me why!

Comment: this can help you http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25165/intermittent-mysql-crashes-with-error-fatal-error-cannot-allocate-memory-for-t

Comment: @c4f4t0r I ran into similar posts around the net, but most of them addresses a MySQL configuration problem; but in my situation, installation itself fails. I don't think the problem is about memory, preconfiguring with debconf-set-selections via shell works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your problem:

```
InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12
```

That errno means you ran out of memory when MySQL attempted to start up. Either reduce the amount of memory MySQL uses, or give the machine more RAM.